# Export to Pdf via rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdf-generation

I need to generate report to pdf file, save on the server, than send the file to the client by email.

I am looking to a gem for exporting pdf file

And I want to know if the file keep all the pdf options (like links and the option to select text copy text etc')

Thanks

Comment: what kind of pdf (only text, draws, images)?

Comment: Text (Color and background color), Tables, images (like pie and logo) Header and footer.

Comment: I know https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf (is simple) and https://github.com/cortiz/prawn-rails  examples here http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf (more powerful but a little less simple)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) gem to generate PDF from HTML. You can configure the options whatever you want in their advanced usage.

Comment: Does this gem generate the html as image or keeping the pdf options like selecting text or separate long text to pages

Comment: No, it will not generate image as PDF. It will generate actual PDF document where you can copy the texts and making hyper links.

Answer (score 0):

Wicked PDF is what you need. It will export to PDF and keep all links, text and images as a real PDF would, because it generates a real, full fledge PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with both WickedPDF and PDFKit is that both use wkhtmltopdf to render the PDFs, and now it is not maintained anymore (public archive).

A more modern option is to use the Grover gem:
https://github.com/Studiosity/grover

It uses Google Puppeteer and Chromium to create PDFs from HTML.